# How do I print the list of changeset hashes on a given branch, in Mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

If I issue this command in terminal in a git repository it gives me commit unique ids or what I know as revision list, like below:

```
$ git rev-list --reverse master  

de1ea6c8a9cd195b348562f42c6cef5bd3555748  
2da45a72621e5c611e0d9f47fa7799fc24476c3c
```

How can I achieve the same result in Mercurial repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's an output customization on the `hg log` command:

```
$ hg log --template '{node}\n'
75f18c4e5caaa5dd1e82f8a1ef1af8f55659fe15
9f15509b1ec305e688f8d524dc902f82000f5526
3199dde60fae0d9b4f9b674a96297bf6c0eec1a6
b3fcf3e324426dc2b5035df18804e8e8044d4f07
11ea8be87677152e1041ee1437c8cc47f0d96115
```

You can supply `-r` to specify which [revset](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) you want to display, like `-r 100:200` (changesets since #100 up to #200) or `-r "ancestors(v1.1)"` (what was included in version 1.1).

Note that you can specify other fields like `{desc}` or `{rev}`. See also [the Mercurial book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html).